# bar chart based on field values

Tags: splunk

An application is generating the performance log file with the following event format:

> datetime sessionid requestid userid invocationTime type
>   invocationContext

For Example:

> 2016-07-22T23:12:50.223 000025b98d67ed Jqpmkt1_ZVMpfmwpPeCKQIs
>   ABCD1234 28 HTTP /mytool/samplecontext

I want to draw a bar chart for a given invocationContext. The bar chart should have number of hits as the bar height and invocationTime buckets as different bars. For example: I want to answer the following questions:

- How many hits for /mytool/samplecontext within last 4 hours had the invocationTime within 0-1000 ms.
- How many hits for /mytool/samplecontext within last 4 hours had the invocationTime within 1001-2000 ms.

And so on. Please suggest how this can be achieved. I have tried to use timechart and I can get charts based on a particular field, but I am not able to group the events in in different buckets based on a field value.

Comment: You say you tried timechart, why not share what you have attempted?

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 ways i've done this in the past

1. Rangemap
   https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.5.0/SearchReference/Rangemap
2. Rounding (I find it presents nicer)
   search ... | eval bin=round(invocationTime/1000,0) | chart count by bin invocationContext | makecontinuous bin